# C++ - match and replace element by value in custom data type vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a vector which contains data for different groups. If I insert new data for a group into a vector it should replace the old data with a new one for the same group number. For this particular example `std::replace` gives an error `std::replace': no matching overloaded function found`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class data
{
    public:
        int group;
        bool condition;
        int time;
        friend bool operator==(const data& lhs, const data& rhs);
        data(int g, bool c, int t) 
        {
            group = g;
            condition = c;
            time = t;
        }
};

bool  operator==(const data& lhs, const data& rhs)
{
    return lhs.group == rhs.group;
}
int main(int argc, char**)
{
    data info_1(10, true , 1);
    data info_2(20, true, 1);
    data info_3(10, false, 4);

    std::vector<data> data_vector;

    data_vector.push_back(info_1);
    data_vector.push_back(info_2);

    std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), data_vector ,info_3);

    std::cout << "vector size: " << data_vector.size() << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < data_vector.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "group number: " << data_vector[i].group << std::boolalpha << " condition: " << data_vector[i].condition << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use a vector instead of a map here?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Frank, no specific reason. It is used everywhere in my actual program.

Comment: @neo, `'std::replace': no matching overloaded function found `

Comment: As for the error, additional info should be posted in the question body and not in the comments.

Comment: And for the map/vector thing, just use a std::map. It'll make your life much easier.

Comment: @Neo How can you solve it with `std::map` if you have your own custom data type?

Comment: `std::replace_if(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), [&info_3](auto&&el) {return el.getGroup() == info_3.getGroup(); }, info_3);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::map`, where the group is the key and the rest of the data is the value.

This way, when you insert to the map a new item is added unless its group number already exist and then it replaces the existing item.

```
class data
{
    public:
        bool condition;
        int time;
        friend bool operator==(const data& lhs, const data& rhs);
        data(bool c, int t) 
        {
            condition = c;
            time = t;
        }
};
```

and then use `std::map<int, Data>` as the container.

You could also implement a wrapper class having a `std::map<int, Data>` as a private member, implementing insertion and iteration (and possibly deletion etc.), and then you could use outside of it an `ExtendedData` or whatever, which is implemented as you implemented `Data` at first.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace the third parameter to `std::replace()` is `const T& old_value`. You are passing the entire vector. That's why you get `no matching overloaded function found`.